# Template parameters in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, templates, parameters

I have a visual studio template of a project in c#. However, there are some differences between the projects created from this template, such as the guid of the project, a project license that takes the form of a string, etc. Hence, I would like to be able to add some custom parameters. I would like visual studio to ask me on the creation of a project from this template what values I would like these custom parameters to take, and for me to insert them. I am not very sure if this is possible and Microsoft's information on this topic is rather scarce and with very few examples.

I have tried adding something like this to .vstemplate file, but this is giving me continuous errors:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$guid1$">
        File1.exe
    </ProjectItem>
    ...
</TemplateContent>
```

Comment: What is your error message you are getting?